# The variable is not of a kind that is allowed in the group C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get my code to match what the following code does:

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, object>() {
                    { "state", new string[] { "Ohio", "Ohio", "Ohio", "Nevada", "Nevada" } },
                    { "year", new int[] { 2000, 2001, 2002, 2001, 2002 } },
                    { "pop", new double[] { 1.5, 1.7, 3.6, 2.4, 2.9 } }
                };
```

My current code:

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, object>() {
                            { "targetValue", calc.ListCalculationData.Select(i => i.MRTargetValue).ToArray<decimal>() },
                            { "ema12", calc.ListCalculationData.Select(i => i.Ema12).ToArray<decimal>() },
                            { "ema26", calc.ListCalculationData.Select(i => i.Ema26).ToArray<decimal>() },
                            { "ema", calc.ListCalculationData.Select(i => i.Ema).ToArray<decimal>() }
                            };

var df1 = DataFrame.FromColumns(data);
var model2 = new LinearRegressionModel(df1, "targetValue ~ ema12 + ema26 + ema"); <= This line gives me the error
```

I'm getting the following error from the api that I'm using which is the extreme optimization C# api and here is the reference url: http://www.extremeoptimization.com/QuickStart/CSharp/DataFrames.aspx

**The variable is not of a kind that is allowed in the group.**

Comment: Why not make it a `Dictionary<string, decimal[]>`?

Comment: Calculation on `decimal`s is very different from calculation on other floating-point types. It's quite probable the library has no support for them. Try `.Cast<double>().ToArray()`.

Comment: @CaiusJard I tried that but I got this error message at the var dfi line
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, decimal[]>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object>'

Comment: @JeroenMostert each object like calc.ListCalculationData.Select(i => i.Ema) is an Ienumerable<decimal>

Comment: What line is giving you the error?

Comment: @ainwood I just edited my question to show which line is giving me the error

Comment: Thanks.  In that case, the problem may not be with the `DataFrame` or the ~Dictionary~, but instead with the LinearRegressionModel.  Does it have a constructor that takes a DataFrame and a string?  It's a strange custom exception to throw.  Is it a compile-time or run-time error?

Comment: @ainwood It is a run-time error and yes it does have a constructor that takes a dataframe and a string.

Comment: Regression models require that the variables be numerical. The error message indicates that the decimal columns are not interpreted as numerical, which would be a bug. All calculations are done in double anyway, so as a work-around, you can use @JeroenMostert's suggestion and use `Cast<double>()` in the definition of the columns.

Comment: @JeffreySax I tried his suggestion and I get this error message: Specified cast is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see any documentation or examples using the `decimal` type, but I cannot verify since I do not have access to the library.

There were some examples using the `double` type. If precision of [15-16 digits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/double) is acceptable, that could be an option. Try defining your `data` variable like this, casting to a `double` in the `Select`, then converting to an array:

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, object>() {
                            { "targetValue", calc.ListCalculationData.Select(i => (double)i.MRTargetValue).ToArray() },
                            { "ema12", calc.ListCalculationData.Select(i => (double)i.Ema12).ToArray() },
                            { "ema26", calc.ListCalculationData.Select(i => (double)i.Ema26).ToArray() },
                            { "ema", calc.ListCalculationData.Select(i => (double)i.Ema).ToArray() }
                            };
```